Create Persistent dock target in Dock.Avalonia
I am trying to create a UI application with Docking/Floating windows (Kinda like Visual Studio) using C#, Avalonia and the Docking system wieslawsoltes/Dock.
However i cant find a way to make the clinet area of the Root window to be a permanent docking target for all the tool windows that are been created, essentially making the root window a "placeholder" for the tool windows.
